# Test case stops until I maximize Browser Window in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am automating test cases with Python Selenium. In my test case, I click a button which open a dialogue box where I enter some data or can upload a file. This dialogue is shown in snapshot below.

[image]

The problem which I am getting is that when I run my test case and minimize browser window, test case stops after button (which open dialogue box) is clicked (dialogue box does not open). As I maximize my browser window, dialogue box appears and my test start doing what it has to do after opening dialogue. If I do not maximize browser window, my test fails.

I tried to put waits (explicit waits) on the visibility of dialogue box/element in dialogue box but still getting this problem.

If I run my tests with my browser windows maximized, my tests execute without any problem.
Can any one help me solving this problem.

Comment: I'd say first look into source of script invoking box, and make sure there isn't some kind of restriction of document size. From your description this seems like server side problem, with possibility of not creating dialog with insufficient document res being most probable one.

Comment: I do not have access to the code. I tried to check code in console but cannot find any thing. There are are other people who faces this issue but no one with good answer. I currently fix this issue by maximizing browser window when required.